# Bintray docker repository storage

Tags: bintray

On Bintray I found out that I have a private docker repository consuming quite a lot of space:

[Account usage by repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1iMr.png)

I then proceeded to do some house keeping and kept only the last 3 tags of all the images I have. However, that didn't help much. The storage didn't change at all after deleting all these old tags.

I got this API endpoint here: https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_get_package_files to have an estimate on the package files size:

```
for img in $(cat images) ; do curl -s -XGET -u "user:pass" https://bintray.com/api/v1/packages/my-org/internal-docker/$img/files | python -m json.tool | jq '.[] | .size' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' ; done
```

Suming all those up gets me 63723101568 bytes, 60GB.

Any idea where the other 310GBs are?

Notice that, even if the 3 tags were completely different from each other, I would get worst case 3x that figure, so 180GB. But the 375GB is still there.

Comment: Also using `POST /usage/package_usage/:subject/:repo/:image_name` and grabbing the storage_bytes yields the same.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the array 'images'?

You are not curling for the entire list but rather single files.

It's possible your list did not include all the images in this repo.

Check to make sure you have traversed all subfolders for images as well.

Comment: ```curl -ns -u user:pass https://mycompany-docker-internal-docker.bintray.io/v2/_catalog | python -m json.tool | jq  '.repositories | .[]' | tr -d '"' | tr '/' ':' > image``` is the list of images and it matches the number see online.

The `files` endpoint gives me all files of all docker layers and their sizes which I then sum.

Comment: When I run the above command I get the list of repos not images. I can see you also look for it w/ your command  jq  '.repositories' which indicates you are pulling this data from the repositories tag. This is not a list of all the images in the docker repo. Thus your source data is wrong and your file sizes are incorrect. At first it confused me too but when I realized a lot of repos have images w/ the same name this is why you ended up w/ only partial data.

Comment: I think bintray just maps the concept of repositories for docker images where each image can potentially have many packages (tags). If I use `curl -ns -u user:pass https://bintray.com/api/v1/repos/mycompany/internal-docker/packages | jq '.[] | .name'` I get even less "repositories" whereas the other command matches the same number I see on the WebGUI (all my docker images).

Answer (score 0):

After some time, [something changed in the backend storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv7Bn.png)

I asked on their support (you have to click on `Feedback` when logged in to Bintary) and they're checking if there was any house keeping done or only after I complained to them something was done.

I'll update if I hear more from them.